# Skipping a nested for loop iteration - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, shapes, nested-for-loop

First off, let me explain what I'm attempting to do.

I'm wanting to print a quadrilateral(square shape) using strings from a list. Like so:

```
John
o  h
h  o
nhoJ
```

I get the printed results I'm wanting except my for loop is printing more than needed. I just need to skip a few loop iterations depending on the length of the actual string.

This is where I need help, this is inside the "quad_text" function:

```
for i in norm_list[1:-1]:           
            for j in reve_list[1:-1]:
                print(f"{i}{spaces}{j}")
```

My outputted results right now:

```
---
John
o  h
o  o
h  h
h  o
nhoJ
---
Joe
o o
eoJ
---
David
a   i
a   v
a   a
v   i
v   v
v   a
i   i
i   v
i   a
divaD
```

Full Code

```
#Global Variables"
normal_list = ["John", "Joe", "David"]
#normal_list = ["Hey there buddy!"]

def initialization():
    rev_list = string_reverser()
    combined_lists = zip(normal_list, rev_list)
    quad_text(list(combined_lists))

def string_reverser():
    reversed_list = []
    for i in normal_list:
        reversed_list.append(i[::-1])
    return(reversed_list)

def quad_text(combined_lists):
    for (norm_list, reve_list) in combined_lists:
        print("---")
        print(norm_list)
        text_len = len(norm_list)
        spaces = (text_len - 2) *(" ")
        for i in norm_list[1:-1]: 
            for j in reve_list[1:-1]: # <--- Problem Area
                print(f"{i}{spaces}{j}")
        print(reve_list)

initialization()
```

Comment: You can use `continue` to go immediately to the next iteration of the current loop.

Comment: Yes ```continue``` could work but dependent on what condition?

Comment: I think your basic algorithm is wrong, you shouldn't be thinking about skipping iterations.

Comment: You shouldn't be using nested loops. Loop over the forward and reverse lists in parallel.

Comment: Ultimately I'm trying to print the single characters of a name in normal order and reverse order on the same line with the correct spaces in between. A  for loop iteration skip seems like the best solution but if there's a better way I'm all for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use nested loops, that creates a cross product between the forward and reverse lists. Use `zip()` to loop over them together.

```
for i, j in zip(norm_list[1:-1], reve_list[1:-1]):
    print(f"{i}{spaces}{j}")
```

Comment: Beautiful, that solves it. 

I don't know why I didn't consider reusing ```zip()``` again like you just did. I suppose since I used ```zip()``` at the top of my code to create the ```combined_lists``` variable, then I converted that back to a list and fed it to my ```quad_text()``` function I didn't know if this would cause some issues or be not pythonic in some way. Anyhow, this works! Thank you.